# Cast to numeric data of length 20 in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My csv file has few numeric data of length 20.  When I read it in dataframes, it is read as dtype object. I need to cast all numeric data to Integer.

My data is csv looks like :

```
emp_id,age,salary,marital
21012334509821345944,22,4500,married
21012334509821345945,22,4510,single
21012334509821345946,22,45040,married
21012334509821345947,22,41500,single
21012334509821345948,22,54500,single
21012334509821345949,22,64500,married
```

I tried :

```
d1 = pd.read_csv('D:\\Exercise\\test.csv')
d1.set_index('emp_id',inplace = True)
d1.index = d1.index.map(int) #OverflowError: int too big to convert
print(d1.index.values)
```

If I comment the index map , I get output like :
['21012334509821345944' '21012334509821345945' '21012334509821345946'
 '21012334509821345947' '21012334509821345948' '21012334509821345949']

But I need integers.
I tried casting the first column alone. 
Is it possible to cast all the data in dataframe if it has numeric value. 
I tried with casting numpy.I face the same error.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas/Numpy keep integers to 64 bits.  Maybe greater, but point is there is a limit.  You need to store them as `dtype` `object` but have the values as `int`.

This is one way:

```
df.emp_id.values[:] = [*map(int, df.emp_id)]
```

Then you can do math.

```
df.emp_id // int(1e10)

0    2101233450
1    2101233450
2    2101233450
3    2101233450
4    2101233450
5    2101233450
Name: emp_id, dtype: object
```

It won't be optimized math, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The largest value that can be represented by an integer (np.uint64) is 18446744073709551615. So, probably you won't be able to do it.